# Sheets are getting grouped in same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook and the main sheet is linked with other sheets by using `VLOOKUP` and nested formulas. When I run a macro all of them get grouped. I want to add a single worksheet before my sheet "RAW" so I can create a pivot table. The code below, however, adds 5 Sheets and I am not sure why.

```
On Error Resume Next

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set ws = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "Raw!R1C1:R50000C41")
Set Pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(ws.Range("A8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have X sheets grouped and run the following:

```
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
```

Excel will use the count of sheets selected as the count of new sheets to create as you've not specified how many to create.

You can over-ride this to create just one sheet:

```
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet, Count:=1
```

Or

```
Sheets.Add Before:=Sheets("RAW"), Count:=1
```

If that's the requirement (it appears to change during edits)

Keep in mind, this will ungroup(de-select) the sheets as it automatically selects the newly created sheet.